# Adding NOT NULL column to SQLite table with references

Tags: sql, sqlite

I need to add a column to my existing SQLite table that references a column in another table.  I use the command

```
ALTER TABLE users 
 ADD COLUMN dayChoice_id INTEGER 
             NOT NULL REFERENCES dayChoice(dayChoice_id) DEFAULT 0
```

And I get the error "Cannot add a REFERENCES column with non-NULL default value".  Is that true?  How would I add the column then?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to solve "Cannot add a NOT NULL column with default value NULL" in SQLite3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170634/how-to-solve-cannot-add-a-not-null-column-with-default-value-null-in-sqlite3)

Comment: @KonstantinV.Salikhov, that's kind of the opposite problem that I'm having.  In their case, the default was NULL.  I have no problem adding the column with NULLs.  But I want to make it non-NULL, specifically DEFAULT 0.

Comment: maybe the error is because the column -"dayChoice_id" in the reference table -"dayChoice" is nullable?

Comment: dayChoice_id is defined - "dayChoice_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY".  I don't think the primary key is nullable, right?

Comment: @Dan-Goodspeed: In SQLite primary keys can hold NULLs, except for some specific cases: _According to the SQL standard, PRIMARY KEY should always imply NOT NULL. Unfortunately, due to a bug in some early versions, this is not the case in SQLite. Unless the column is an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY or the table is a WITHOUT ROWID table or the column is declared NOT NULL, SQLite allows NULL values in a PRIMARY KEY column._ (more details at: http://sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html )

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to disable foreign keys enforcing for the time of executing this `ALTER` statement, like this:

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys = 0;
ALTER TABLE users ADD COLUMN dayChoice_id INTEGER
            NOT NULL REFERENCES dayChoice(dayChoice_id) DEFAULT 0;
PRAGMA foreign_keys = 1;
```

Answer (score 7):

From the [docs](http://sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html):

> If foreign key constraints are enabled and a column with a REFERENCES clause is added, the column must have a default value of NULL.

The default value you supplied was not NULL.

It's not compatible with another requirement:

> If a NOT NULL constraint is specified, then the column must have a default value other than NULL.

You can probably work around the problem by temporarily disabling foreign key constraints before the `ALTER TABLE`.